# Custom AuthorizationFilter is not called when using role-based authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

Since I updated from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0, my custom AuthorizationFilter stopped working - it is not being called, and returns Unauthorized - when I use it on an Action annotation allowing roles (`[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]`). When it is a simple `[CustomAuthorize]`, it works fine.

CustomAuthorize is a class that extends AuthorizeAttribute and IAsyncAuthorizationFilter. Overly simplifying, this is the roles part:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ADMIN"));
        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
        context.HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
    }
}
```

On `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization();
```

I also tried including `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>();`, but it redirects the user to a "Unauthorized" page, and still does not validate the role.

Full `Configure` method on `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `CustomAuthorize`? Do you sign with identity account? Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: what happen if you just write Autorize instead of CustomAuthorize? sounds like your CustomAuthorize is the problem

Comment: I added more info on the CustomAuthorize. I wrote it to call my DB and get the role list. It will also update the user's last login date, so I would like to keep it as a custom code.

Comment: have you called app.UseAuthentication(); in Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) ?

Comment: I have added both `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the order. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?#migrate-startupconfigure): _If the app uses authentication/authorization features such as AuthorizePage or [Authorize], place the call to UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization: after, UseRouting and UseCors, but before UseEndpoints._ How do you inject CustomAuthorizeAttribute? Can you show that code?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I edited the question to include the full Configure method, but it is already following the order you described.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work reverting the Endpoint Routing. It surely is not a long term fix, but...

On `ConfigureServices`, replaced:

```
services.AddMvc()
```

by:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
                    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
```

And on `Configure`, replaced:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

by:

```
app.UseMvc();
```